# Проверить конфликты для merge'а без смены ветки

Tags: git, git-merge

Представим, что я сейчас нахожусь на коммите `1111111111`.

Не меняя локальных файлов я хочу проверить, возникнут ли конфликты при мёрдже коммитов `2222222222` и `3333333333`. Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Может это покажет? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-tree

Comment: @AlexeyTen, да, похоже, только он не возвращает статус, получается надо парсить вывод, что так себе. И ещё не очень в батник загоняется, сейчас смотрю как пайп упихать в for.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, написал ответ, сможешь улучшить?

Answer (score 1):

Более-менее получилось (спасибо [@AlexeyTen](/users/190728/alexey-ten) за подсказку), но смущает тот факт, что приходится парсить патч (впрочем, он парсится верно, поскольку во всех строках кроме искомых вторым символом идёт пробел - спасибо [@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)). Есть проблемы со слишком длинными строками, но вряд ли мы ищем строки длиннее 8192 символов.

```
@echo off

set ancestor=no-such-branch
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('git merge-base %1 %2') do set ancestor=%%x

if %ancestor%==no-such-branch (echo Failed to find ancestor & exit /b 1)

git merge-tree %ancestor% %1 %2 | findstr /b "+<<<<<<< -<<<<<<<" >nul && echo Conflicts found || echo No conflicts
```

Использование:

```
>check-conflicts.bat 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333
No conflicts

>check-conflicts.bat 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222 000
fatal: Not a valid object name 000
Failed to find ancestor

>check-conflicts.bat 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222 4444444444444444444444444444444444444444
Conslicts found

>check-conflicts.bat master develop
FINDSTR: Слишком длинная строка 95913.
No conflicts
```

Comment: в патче комбинация <<<<<<< будет соответствовать только тому, что Вы ожидаете. Вы не сделаете так, что бы в патче появилось <<<<<<< с другим значением. Никак - потому что в начало каждой строки добавляется два пробела или "+ " или "- ". Поэтому, что бы ложных случаев избежать, нужно добавить символов ^$ или ключи /b /e (надо протестировать, я только в документацию подглядывал)

Comment: @KoVadim, что-то у меня не получилось. Попытка поставить `findstr /b /r "[-+] <<<<<<<"` на одном примере выдала неверный результат (нашлись конфликты, которых не было), а на другом стала работать более 20 минут (я прибил так и не дождавшись) вместо 6 секунд. В чём косяк?

Comment: я не специалист в батниках... к сожалению.

Comment: @KoVadim, допилил. Но всё-таки меня смущает необходимость парсить патч :)

Answer (score 1):

при наличии posix-совместимой оболочки и программы *grep*:

```
#!/bin/sh

b=$(git merge-base $1 $2)

if [ -z "$b" ]; then echo "не удалось найти общего предка для $1 и $2"; exit; fi

if git merge-tree "$b" $1 $2 | grep -q '^+<<<<<<<'; then
  echo "есть конфликты"
else
  echo "нет конфликтов"
fi
```

использование:

```
$ этот-скрипт хэш-или-метка-1 хэш-или-метка-2
```

доп. чтение: [`man git-merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) [`man git-merge-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-tree)

Comment: переписал мой скрипт на bash? только выхода не хватает при ошибке с предком. а почему ищешь только `+<<<<<<<`, а такой же с минусом - нет? и неужели от патча никак не избавиться?

Comment: 1. нет, для любой posix-совместимой оболочки. 2. а откуда там возьмётся с минусом? 3. https://stackoverflow.com/q/501407/4827341

Comment: 2. Я думал, с минусом тоже может быть... 3. Да, видел тот вопрос. Только что-то пропустил ответ с merge-tree. Там по идее вопрос немного другой - он хочет в текущую ветку merge проверять.

Comment: 2. это ж вывод diff-а, аналогичный (если не первоисточник) накладываемому командой merge. такие строки в данном случае могут быть **только** добавлены.